# Scala: Condense Array[(String, Array[Double])] to Array[(String)]

Tags: arrays, scala, dictionary

I have an array that looks like this Array((1,Array(1.0,0.0,3.0)), (2,Array(0.0,2.0,1.0))) that I want to turn into and array that looks like: Array((1,1.0,0.0,3.0),(2,0.0,2.0,1.0)).

Is there an easy way to do that?  I'm guessing there is some sort of map I can do but I haven't been able to figure out the syntax.

Thanks.

Comment: Someone else has asked an almost identical question recently, only I can't find it right now. Could you expand on the use-case you have that needs this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please specify the types of input and output. As i understand the task is Array[String, Array[Double]] => Array[Array[Double]]

```
 scala> val r = Array(("1", Array(1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 3.0)), ("2", Array(0.0, 2.0, 1.0)))
r: Array[(String, Array[Double])] = Array((1,Array(1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 3.0)), (2,Array(0.0, 2.0, 1.0)))

scala> val res = r map { case (s, Array(xs @ _*)) => (s.toDouble +: xs).toArray }
res: Array[Array[Double]] = Array(Array(1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 3.0), Array(2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0))
```

Comment: This is getting me where I want to go.  The output data types isn't exactly what I am looking for (the first element should be a string, not Double, but you couldn't tell that form the example I gave) but that's easy enough to change.  Can you provide any explanation around "Array(xs @ _*)", particularly what the "@ _*" is doing?  Thanks very much!

Comment: Look here about "@ _*" http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-symbols.html. Roughly, it's a way to unnaply Array as vararg expansion.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this:

```
a.map { case (a, Array(b,c,d)) => (a,b,c,d) }
```

---

```
scala> val a = Array((1,Array(1.0,0.0,3.0)), (2,Array(0.0,2.0,1.0)))
a: Array[(Int, Array[Double])] = Array((1,Array(1.0, 0.0, 3.0)), (2,Array(0.0, 2.0, 1.0)))

scala> a.map({ case (a, Array(b,c,d)) => (a,b,c,d) })
res4: Array[(Int, Double, Double, Double)] = Array((1,1.0,0.0,3.0), (2,0.0,2.0,1.0))
```

---

A solution with support for up to 22-tuple. Of course, even this one assumes that all array members have the same lengths.

```
a.map {
  case (a, Array(b))           => (a,b)
  case (a, Array(b,c))         => (a,b,c)
  case (a, Array(b,c,d))       => (a,b,c,d)
  // pseudo-scala
  case (n1, Array(n2,...,n22)) => (n1,n2,...,n22)
}
```

Comment: and what about when the inside array's size is >100. How can you flatten that?

Comment: That works great, the only problem is that is the number of elements in the array might be different depending on the data I feed to the function that generates the array (but would be consistent in any given instance of the array.  so I might have Array((1,Array(1,2,3)),(2,Array(2,3,4)), but might later have Array((1,Array(1,2)),(2,Array(2,3)).  Is there a way to genericize the expression of the array in the case statement?  I'm new to Scala and so don;t understand the nuances of all the syntax.  Thanks.

Comment: @JCalbreath given that in Scala tuples support up to 22 elements, you can always list all 22 possible cases. For even more extensibility, you'd have to start using an `HList` implementation, such as the one in shapeless library. I don't have experience with that, though.

Comment: @JCalbreath are you sure you don't want to construct `Array` instances instead of tuple instances? For example: `Array(1, Array(2,3,4))` would become `Array(Array(1,2,3,4))`. An `HList` would be overfill for a collection with homogenous element types.

Comment: I'm not really sure of anything right now :)  I think the Array instances would work fine.